# A summer house, a cottage or a cabin?

Tags: word-choice, british-english

When I want to refer to a (rural) vacation home, what would be the most appropriate term in BrE? I know in American English *cabin* and *camp* are used for those, but what would correspond to those in British English? What I've come up with are *summer house* or *summer cottage*, but I want to avoid the connotation of those small buildings in gardens.

For visual reference, this would be something I'm after here.
http://cedarcottagebc.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/07/cedar_cottage_exterior.jpg

edit: I got the term wrong, thank you for making me realize it!

Comment: Your notion of what American English words are used for a _rural vacation home_ comes from what sources? People who have "cabins" call them cabins, but that's rare. They would be more likely to say "my country house". A "camp" is something entirely different from a _rural vacation home_. Why **summer** home or cottage? Do you think that people in the UK don't go their country houses in the winter?

Comment: My notion of the American English words mainly come from exchange with speakers of American English. But as you can see, that is not relevant here at all.

_Summer_ in this case is optional with _cottage_, but I wanted to include it, especially in _summer home_ to distinguish between seasonal getaways and permanent homes.

Comment: Looking at the image, in British English we would tend to call that a **cabin**.  Cabin is often used to refer to small building, usually of wooden construction.  If this is situated in a garden (and therefore not the main building), it would be a **summer house** in addition to being a cabin.

Comment: If what Americans call them isn't relevant, then **you shouldn't have mentioned it in your question**. After all, what you're looking for is how BrE speakers refer to the entities you're asking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generic term in British English is [***holiday home***](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/holiday-home) (this is more common than summer home) - this covers all types of building.  Cottage and cabin are types of building.  A camp is a place/area where people stay, rather than a building or home.

Comment: Thank you! I'm aware of what a camp is, but in some areas in the US they use the word to describe a cottage.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear whether you're suggesting that ***summer home/cottage*** suggests *small buildings in gardens*, or whether you're referring to ***cabin*** & ***camp*** in that respect. We certainly wouldn't use the latter two terms (unless ***cabin*** were an accurate description of the type of building).

[Edit in response to OP's comment: *Summer **house*** might mean a *small building in a garden* (something which I overlooked and which, I think, would probably be more commonly used in the context of a large house with a large garden), but *summer **home*** wouldn't mean that.]

I think we would often just refer to it as a ***second home*** or even something like *They've also got **a place** in [village/town/county/country name]*. Both terms could also apply to places abroad, particularly places in more southern parts of Europe, which may be used more in our winter than in our summer.

Comment: Oxford Dictionaries Online define _summer house_ as follows: "_noun_ a small building in a garden, used for sitting in during fine weather" in British and World Englishes. That lead me into thinking that I should avoid using that word for it.

However, in US English they also have "(usually summer house) a cottage or house use as a second residence, especially during the summer".

Comment: See my edited response. I also agree with ***holiday home*** as suggested by Soccem.

Comment: Yes, I noticed my error, which probably caused some of the confusion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have what you have pictured in the link... and i certainly call it a cabin, because a cabin is what it is and i guess more specifically it serves as a summer house, although summerhouse might be misunderstood by non BrE to mean a house you travel to in the summer, like a holiday home, you only live in during the summer, and return to another domicile in the winter, aka here as second home. Old thread, i realise, but someone else might be reading it nowadays, so for their interest, i post.